# Convert user input to unicode

Tags: c, input, unicode

So, I'm trying to get some input from the user in a C program, doing `fscanf(stdin, "%s", buffer)`
When I input the character `å` i get a value of 134 which corresponds to the codepage 437.

But when i use the windows function `GetACP()` i get 1252 as the active codepage and 134 doesn't match `å` in that codepage. I tried setting the codepage to UTF-8 but that didn't give me any input at all.

Is there a way of getting the corresponding codepage for user input and convert that to unicode format? Or if there's a better way of getting the input.

I've been looking around a lot and I can't find much info on this.

Comment: Windows console programs use a different code page than the rest of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code page used by the console window is called the OEM code page for historical reasons. You can get the default code page with [`GetOEMCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318114(v=vs.85).aspx) and the currently selected code page with [`GetConsoleCP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683162(v=vs.85).aspx).

You can set the console to use UTF-8 with the command `chcp 65001`, but Microsoft does not guarantee it to work in all cases.

If you don't need normal C++ I/O to the console, you can use the [Console Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx) instead e.g. WriteConsoleW to output a Unicode string.

Comment: I don't need to display UTF characters on the console, merely get the input from the console in a unicode format UTF-8 or similar. When i set the codepage to 65001 the buffer was empty after i input a character.